# IIS Root Path vs Path of virtual directory

Tags: asp.net

I am using code that will get the root path

```
return HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"\Schedules\");
```

This works great when my site is installed as a fully fledged web app. but when its installed as a virtual directory it breaks, because it is looking for files in root folder, and not in \virtualdirectorypath folder.

Is there a way I can change the code to look for files from the virtual directory root, but also so it won't break if the app is installed as a fully fledged website?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
return HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/Schedule/");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ~ root operator.

```
Server.MapPath("~"); // path of root of web application.
```

Answer (score 0):

See my answer on [Base URL in ASP.net Master Pages with virtual Directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452850/base-url-in-asp-net-master-pages-with-virtual-directories/5828049#5828049)