# Managing relative paths to css/js files in ASP .NET Master Page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

in my master page I have

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and plenty other script/link elements. That works fine if rendered page in on the same level as master page file. If I try to access page that is in subfolder, request to js/css files is wrong.

I tried:

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but it only works if there's no application virtual path. If my application is located under:

```
http://localhost/virtualPath/subfolder/Page.aspx
```

then request goes to:

```
http://localhost
```

I tried to use ResolveClientUrl, but my head is defined as

```
<head runat="server">
```

so I get an error. Is there a way to nicely solve that issue?

Note: I can't remove runat from head tag as I'm using themes

Comment: I hope you will get this answer at this link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452850/base-url-in-asp-net-master-pages-with-virtual-directories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add the link on the Init procedure using the server.mappath() function

http://www.dotnetgenerics.com/Modules/TricksAndTips/ASP.NET/PowerOfTilda.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632(v=vs.90).aspx

This will not work in your preview on visual studio but will work.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't have to appear in the head section so you go back to your ResolveClientUrl solution and have your references inside the body tag.
The css should be part of your theme so will be added automatically

Comment: I need to control the order of css files so I need to include these manually. When it comes to JS, when I tried you solution it broke my pages due to many script sections in page's head tag. Thanks though :)

Comment: You could move all the javascript in the page's head tag into the body tag. Isn't your css part of theme? (you could use specifity instead of relying on css order,  http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/ )

Comment: I have 2 files that are some kind of "core" css files: normalize.css + core.css, that look the same regardless of theme. This is why I don't want to have a separate copies of that files for every theme. When it comes to JS: yes, I could do it. But I have plenty of pages to test if I make such a change. I was looking for quick solution. Thanks though! :)