# From within an ISAPI filter, how to determine the virtual path for an IIS application?

Tags: iis, isapi

Is there a way, inside an ISAPI Filter, to determine the virtual path for the IIS application or virtual directory?

It's basically the same question as [IIS Root Path vs Path of virtual directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271260), but rather than within an ASP.NET application, I want this from within an ISAPI filter.

Does the value of the server variable APPL_MD_PATH always ends with the actual virtual path of an application?  Is it true that the format of APPL_MD_PATH is always

```
/LM/W3SVC/<sitenumber>/ROOT/<Website_vdir>
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know for sure, but I am guessing that the format for APPL_MD_PATH is always as above, so one can just get the tail segment of that server variable to get the virtual path.

Need to special case the root vdir.